# Svg Use element

Tags: svg

[this is the link on codepen](https://codepen.io/E_M_4ever/pen/bmVrMb)in this example why I can't choose the text on the others to use element, I searched and tried too much without any solutions.

```
<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="bmVrMb" data-default-tab="html,result" data-user="E_M_4ever" data-pen-title="Svg Progress Bar" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/E_M_4ever/pen/bmVrMb/">Svg Progress Bar</a> by Ehab (<a href="https://codepen.io/E_M_4ever">@E_M_4ever</a>) on 
<a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: The purpose of <use> is to have copies of a template. Since you don't wan t that, <use> is not appropriate for your use case.

Comment: thanks for your reply, that is mean I should duplicate my elements to do what I want

Comment: Please do not post links to code. Please include relevant code sections inline in your question to avoid link rot.

Comment: ok, thanks for your advice @MichaelMullany